# does FragmentPagerAdapter will restore view status automatic?

Tags: android, fragment

I have a ViewPager with a FragmentPagerAdapter.
the ViewPager has many pages, when I swipe it,the fragment's some methods will be called.
I create a new view in 'onCreateView', and init the data in 'onActivityCreated'.
but it sames like the view will restore its status automatically when it has recreated.

I mean: the pager has 4 pages. I scroll the listview to the bottom at page 1, and the i swipe the pager to the forth, and then i swipe it to the first. the listview shows at the bottom.  but actually the listview is a new one. why?

the code:

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment{
    View onCreateView(){ 
        ListView listview=new ListView();
        return listview;
    }

    void onActivityCreated(){
        List list=getdata();
        listview.setAdapter(new Adapter(list));
    }
}
```

btw:I don't hold the view in my Fragment.
    I don't call the ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit().
    I create a new view in onCreateView.
    I create a new Adapter in onActivityCreated.

so why the listview can locate to the bottom(any position i scroll to the last time) automatically?

I don't find any code to do this in Fragment or FragmentPagerAdapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the FragmentManagerImpl, there is a method named moveToState, it will call saveFragmentViewState() method when the fragment move out,the the "saveHierarchyState" method of the fragment's view will be called,so the state is saved and hold by the fragment.And fragmentmanagerimple will restore it automatically.